# Water droplets on inside of glass that covers headlight

Tags: headlight

I am seeing water droplets on inside of the glass that covers the headlights. They don't seem to go away. How can I fix this?

I think I found the answer here:
http://www.ehow.com/how_5035812_remove-condensation-headlights.html

Comment: +1 for answering your own question. Good link, but I don't know if I would put the headlights in the oven. Just let the sun dry them out and then make sure your seals are good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the link shows how to remove the condensation it doesn't deal with the cause.The seal has failed and that what is allowing moisture to accumulate.After drying reseal with 3M window seal.It comes on roll and sticks to about anything.Wrap a bead around the light assembly where the lens is glued the housing.Also check the seal where the bulb socket mounts.I would not use the window seal on the socket as you will not be able to remove it later.

Answer (score 3):

This has happened to my Hyundai Santro's headlights the last time it rained, when I did not use it for a while. The service center guys said the lights have to be replaced. I don't know about other cars, but for a Santro headlight assembly, there is a water vent closed by a rubber bud that is situated near the indicator connection. You can remove the headlight from the car and drain all the water through this vent, replace it and then put the headlight back in place. For the remaining drops, you can run the car with headlights on (even in daylight) so that the remaining water drops can evaporate and come out through the same vent.